# MySQL Users with exact same privilege, FIRST can connect and the other DONT

Tags: mysql, database-connection, ubuntu-server, sql-grant, mysql-8.0

I'll try to explain in few words what is happening here...

I'd created a clean instance of a MySQL 8 database, on an Ubuntu Server (18.04) release.
The database is working perfectly fine, I can connect local and remotely include using SSH from another server.

For the record,

```
user@server:~$ mysql -u root -p
Enter password:
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 44
```

and while connected, I issue this command `SELECT HOST, USER FROM user` on **mysql** db and get:

```
+---------------+------------------+
| HOST          | USER             |
+---------------+------------------+
| 192.168.0.xxx | phpMyAdmin       |
| localhost     | mysql.infoschema |
| localhost     | mysql.session    |
| localhost     | mysql.sys        |
| localhost     | root             |
+---------------+------------------+
```

So far, so good. Next step, I create a specific user (let's name it Usr1 for instance):
`CREATE USER Usr1@'192.168.0.xxx' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'foo'`
and repeat exact the same command three more times, changing only username and password, not anything else.

When I try to connect remotely (using the host I've already specified in the user creation), usr3 is able to connect, but user1 and user2 not; for these users, I see this error:

```
user@192.168.0.xxx:~$ mysql -u User1 -h 192.168.0.yyy -p
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'User1'@'192.168.0.xxx' (using password: YES)
user@192.168.0.xxx:~$ mysql -u User2 -h 192.168.0.yyy -p
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'User2'@'192.168.0.xxx' (using password: YES)
```

And I'm quite sure I'm not writing the password wrong!
Using "User3" I'm able to connect and query the database, no problem. Using "User1" ou "User2", I get the message error above.

Then, despite of writing the same exact command for each user, I query mysql.user table, and compare each column from the result; as expected, all columns are exact the same value, except the User and password, of course. I display the results here, for the sake of clarity, but as I already mentioned, the columns are exactly same...

```
+---------------+----------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+---------------+--------------+-----------+------------+-----------------+------------+------------+--------------+------------+-----------------------+------------------+--------------+-----------------+------------------+------------------+----------------+---------------------+--------------------+------------------+------------+--------------+------------------------+----------+------------------------+--------------------------+----------------------------+---------------+-------------+-----------------+----------------------+-----------------------+-------------------------------------------+------------------+-----------------------+-------------------+----------------+------------------+----------------+------------------------+---------------------+--------------------------+-----------------+
| Host          | User     | Select_priv | Insert_priv | Update_priv | Delete_priv | Create_priv | Drop_priv | Reload_priv | Shutdown_priv | Process_priv | File_priv | Grant_priv | References_priv | Index_priv | Alter_priv | Show_db_priv | Super_priv | Create_tmp_table_priv | Lock_tables_priv | Execute_priv | Repl_slave_priv | Repl_client_priv | Create_view_priv | Show_view_priv | Create_routine_priv | Alter_routine_priv | Create_user_priv | Event_priv | Trigger_priv | Create_tablespace_priv | ssl_type | ssl_cipher             | x509_issuer              | x509_subject               | max_questions | max_updates | max_connections | max_user_connections | plugin                | authentication_string                     | password_expired | password_last_changed | password_lifetime | account_locked | Create_role_priv | Drop_role_priv | Password_reuse_history | Password_reuse_time | Password_require_current | User_attributes |
+---------------+----------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+---------------+--------------+-----------+------------+-----------------+------------+------------+--------------+------------+-----------------------+------------------+--------------+-----------------+------------------+------------------+----------------+---------------------+--------------------+------------------+------------+--------------+------------------------+----------+------------------------+--------------------------+----------------------------+---------------+-------------+-----------------+----------------------+-----------------------+-------------------------------------------+------------------+-----------------------+-------------------+----------------+------------------+----------------+------------------------+---------------------+--------------------------+-----------------+
| 192.168.0.xxx | User1    | N           | N           | N           | N           | N           | N         | N           | N             | N            | N         | N          | N               | N          | N          | N            | N          | N                     | N                | N            | N               | N                | N                | N              | N                   | N                  | N                | N          | N            | N                      |          | 0x                     | 0x                       | 0x                         |             0 |           0 |               0 |                    0 | mysql_native_password | *                                         | N                | 2020-04-10 19:43:13   |              NULL | N              | N                | N              |                   NULL |                NULL | NULL                     | NULL            |
| 192.168.0.xxx | User2    | N           | N           | N           | N           | N           | N         | N           | N             | N            | N         | N          | N               | N          | N          | N            | N          | N                     | N                | N            | N               | N                | N                | N              | N                   | N                  | N                | N          | N            | N                      |          | 0x                     | 0x                       | 0x                         |             0 |           0 |               0 |                    0 | mysql_native_password | *                                         | N                | 2020-04-10 19:42:54   |              NULL | N              | N                | N              |                   NULL |                NULL | NULL                     | NULL            |
| 192.168.0.xxx | User3    | N           | N           | N           | N           | N           | N         | N           | N             | N            | N         | N          | N               | N          | N          | N            | N          | N                     | N                | N            | N               | N                | N                | N              | N                   | N                  | N                | N          | N            | N                      |          | 0x                     | 0x                       | 0x                         |             0 |           0 |               0 |                    0 | mysql_native_password | *                                         | N                | 2020-04-10 18:34:12   |              NULL | N              | N                | N              |                   NULL |                NULL | NULL                     | NULL            |
+---------------+----------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+---------------+--------------+-----------+------------+-----------------+------------+------------+--------------+------------+-----------------------+------------------+--------------+-----------------+------------------+------------------+----------------+---------------------+--------------------+------------------+------------+--------------+------------------------+----------+------------------------+--------------------------+----------------------------+---------------+-------------+-----------------+----------------------+-----------------------+-------------------------------------------+------------------+-----------------------+-------------------+----------------+------------------+----------------+------------------------+---------------------+--------------------------+-----------------+
```

Ran out of ideas from this point.
Any thoughts?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to understand (or somewhat that resembles understanding...) what was the problem.
Regardless of issuing the exact same command for each user, the first one I'd created with direct access to the server where MySQL is installed. The other two users were created in another server, the one where phpMyAdmin and Apache is installed.

For any unknown (at least for me) reason, the users I'd created using "root"@"IP" was unable to connect to the MySQL installation, while the user I'd created using "root"@"localhost" was connecting fine. I dropped and recreated the users, using "root"@"localhost" account, and they were able to connect to database - despite the information on mysql.user table still the same.

Anyway, now I can connect using all three accounts, each one with access to specific databases, as I intended from the beginning.